# Unable to determine the regex for a path format which could be stringA/stringB/StringX or stringA/stringX but not just stringA/stringB

Tags: javascript, regex

This regex is in JavaScript. More specifically stringA = `content`, stringB = `dam` & stringx could be any string.
I have tried this regex & few others:

```
^\/(content(?!\/(dam)))\/(.*)
```

but this would recognize

```
/content/asfcew
/content/reddam
/content/usa/texas
```

and would not recognize

```
/content/dam
```

which is good, but alongside it also does not recognize

```
/content/dam/asdfafa
/content/damred
```

which is not good.

Any suggestions are much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add an end-of-string anchor `$` to the look-ahead:

```
^\/(content(?!\/(dam$)))\/(.*)
                    ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY7wP2/1)

Now, `(?!\/(dam$))` will only fail the match when `dam` appears before the end of string.

Note that there are too many capturing groups here, you may remove them like this:

```
^\/content(?!\/dam$)\/(.*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/nY7wP2/2)

Comment: Thanks for the edit and the solution, works great for me.

Answer (score 1):

As the poster above said, you need an end of string anchor `$` to the look ahead group.

To enable it capture both /content/dam and the rest use this pattern.

```
> ^\/(content(?=|\/(dam$)))\/(.*)
```

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/kO2cZ1/5